# Mysql tar ball installation

Tags: mysql, installation

I need to install two different versions of Mysql in one server OS RHEL6 and it will be separated by user called mysqlprod and mysqlpreprod.

I need to separate their binaries, softwares,data directory and mysqldaemons.

I assume tar ball installation is a best way to deviate the installations. But I don't find tar ball for Mysql 5.6.17 in http://dev.mysql.com/downloads downloads. Its just rpms and I cannot do "rpm --basedir=" because it says rpm cannot be relocatable.

Where can I find tar ball binaries that is provided in http://dev.mysql.com/downloads ? or anyother way to achieve my above setup in Mysql 5.6.17 latest GA? Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tarballs are at the bottom of the list of downloads after you select "Linux - Generic" from the operating system drop-down... not under "Red Hat Enterprise Linux."

Assumuming you are 64-bit, the one you're looking for is called "Linux - Generic (glibc 2.5) (x86, 64-bit), Compressed TAR Archive."